# Excel: Check if Cell value exists in Column, and return a value in the same row as match but different column

Tags: range, match, excel-formula

In a single workbook i have 2 worksheets named Master and Software.

I want to search a range of cells in column F of Software and IF the value '1' exists in it AND IF 'Software' column B has a text value of 'Antivirus', I want to return to 'Master' the cell value of 'Software' column F FOR THE ROW THAT MATCHES THE VALUE 1.

I tried this but i get errors that i can't debug:

=IFERROR(INDEX($Software!F$7:$Software!F$1000,MATCH(1,$Software!A$7:$Software!A$1000,0),1),"no match")

Anyone see what i'm doing wrong please?

It's like a steering wheel down my pants - driving me nuts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the value '1' you are seeking change based on data in Master?

Can you move columns around in the Software tab?

vlookup might provide an easier solution.

As a sample mockup for the 'Software' tab:

```
Row Software                Number
1   test                    1
2   test                    3
3   AntiVirus               1
4   AntiVirus               2
5   test                    4
```

Then a forumla on Master to pull back Row 3 that would match your question would be:

```
=INDEX(Software!A:A,MATCH(1,(Software!B:B = "AntiVirus")*(Software!F:F=1),0))
```

***Important, when you put this in the cell, to get Excel to evaluate it as an array you must press CTRL + Shift + Enter
This will add { } around the function when viewed in the forumla bar.

Comment: hi - thanks for your response.  The value 1 changes but not based on data in Master.  I can move columns around in Software if that helps... I don't really know vlookup...Thx

Comment: vlookup is very handy if you only need to find one value and return one correlated value.  It sounds like you are doing two.  I think you are on the right track using INDEX and MATCH.  I will edit my answer block above